# How to use spy from jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am very new to Angular and jasmine and I am facing issues while I am doing mock:

```
public uploadFile(confirm) {
  this.uploadModalRef.close();
  if (this.filePath.length) {
    let ngbModalOptions: NgbModalOptions = {
       backdrop : 'static',
       keyboard : 'false',
       windowClass: 'custom-class'
    };
    this.importModalRef = this.modalservice.open(confirm, ngbModalOption);
  }
}
```

Here is what I am trying:

```
it('should upload the file', () => {
  let close: "11";
  let filepath;
  component.uploadFile;
  expect(component.uploadFile([filePath]) = ['11'].toBe(close);
});
```

But still if conditions was highlighted in code coverage and `this.uploadModalref`

Please let me know what iam doing wrong here.

Comment: It seems like your test is not completed yet and has some bugs. I've tried somehow to edit it but didn't understand the aim of your test. Could you fix it - what you're expecting from your test file?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply actually iam trying cover my code using above spec but while iam running the code coverage if conditions have not covered and else part not covered actually I don’t how to do

Comment: Got it. Added an example in the answers, please check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created simple unit test for `uploadFile` method: the test expects that `modalService.open` will be called with mocked params when we have non-empty `filePath` array:

```
 describe('HelloComponent', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;
  let component: HelloComponent;
  const modalService: NgbModal = jasmine.createSpyObj('modalService', ['open']);

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ HelloComponent, TestComponent ],
      providers: [{
        provide: NgbModal,
        useValue: modalService
      }]
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    component = fixture.debugElement.children[0].componentInstance;

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should call modalService.open on uploadFile', () => {
    component.filePath = 'File1';
    component.uploadModalRef = jasmine.createSpyObj('uploadModalRef', ['close']);
    let mockOptions: NgbModalOptions = {
      backdrop : 'static',
      keyboard : false,
      windowClass: 'custom-class'
    };
    const mockConfirm = 'confirm-template';

    component.uploadFile(mockConfirm);

    expect(modalService.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockConfirm, mockOptions);
  });
});
```

Since your component depends on `NgbModal` we have to mock this injector and for this we can create [jasmine spy object](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3EcreateSpyObj%3C/code%3E):

```
const modalService: NgbModal = jasmine.createSpyObj('modalService', ['open']);
```

Then we provide `NgbModal` into test module providers using our created spy object. This will allow us to spy on it methods (for this example it's `open` method).

In the test itself we follow AAA pattern: arrange act assert. First we arrange class properties and method arguments by creating mock data. Then we call the target function `uploadFile`. And lastly - we're expecting that `modalService.open` method will be called with correct arguments. You can also add another unit tests based on this example by changing mock data. For example:

```
it('should not call modalService.open on uploadFile when filePath is empty', () => {
    component.filePath = '';
    component.uploadModalRef = jasmine.createSpyObj('uploadModalRef', ['close']);
    const mockConfirm = 'confirm-template';

    component.uploadFile(mockConfirm);

    expect(modalService.open).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Since there is an if statement in the `uploadFile` method, the `modalService.open` method will not be called if the `filePath` array is empty. This is exactly what we expect in the last example.

Also created a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-testing-sherlock-hznoyy?file=app/hello.component.spec.ts), so you can check it out here.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Hi @sherlock.92 I am getting error while implementing in my code ‘type string [] is not assignable to type string’ for component.filePath = [‘file’]; for this line kindly let me know what iam doing wrong here

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I thought your file path is an array. So I've updated the answer. In your tests you have to write `component.filePath = 'File1';` or `component.filePath = '';` if you want to test another case.

Comment: Hi one more request if say else path not covered please let me know what I have to do

Comment: not sure if i understand you correctly, what do you mean ?

Comment: The problem is it says else path not covered in code coverage for this method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178990/discussion-between-mahadevan-and-sherlock-92).